# Software for rescuing files from corrupted FAT32 USB stick

Tags: usb, data-recovery

A 8GB USB stick with FAT32 has got corrupted (Windows 8). 
In a directory, instead of files, I see a lot of "byte garbage". 
Looks as if some information was written directly into the directory listing, instead of into a file.

Can you recommend a good tool which can rescue information and write it in ANOTHER place?  (Nothing that writes to the USB stick itself.)

Comment: The software has to run on Windows 8? Or can it be for other operating systems, too (if yes, which)?

Comment: @unor Well, Windows is preferred (7 or 8); but I have also a Mac here; and if the software is really good, I'd also go through the hassle and install Ubuntu ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For years now I have been using [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/features) (from the author of [Ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)) to do just that.

It works and it is free.

Comment: Thank you! Can't vote you up in the moment, because I need 15 rep points ......

Comment: Well, when you get them, please accept this as the answer - not that I want the points, just to show future visitors that it is the answer. Welcome aboard. I am glad to have been of help.